# Docker network bridge not working from outside

Tags: docker, jenkins, networking

I am trying to start a jenkins container. The port 8080 is mapped to the host port 80.

`docker run -p 80:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts`

I can curl the jenkins app from the host, however I can not reach it from outside the host.

`curl localhost:80` works inside host

but

`curl <fqdn or ip address>:80` does not work outside host (same network as host) and timeout.

If I set --net=host, the above command works, but I would like to not use the host network in case I need to add more services in the future.

I think it is not a firewall issue because by setting the network to host, the link is working.

With tcpdump I can see the requests in the host main interface, however, no packets are forwarded to the docker0 interface. Is it normal behaviour ?

What can I do to resolve the issue in order to reach jenkins outside the host ?

Comment: what does `docker ps -a` shows?  `0.0.0.0:80->8080/tcp`? can you try to use another port (rather than 80) to ensure it's not filtered by your network?

Comment: Yes it shows 0.0.0.0:80->8080/tcp. This time I have tried with port 8080. It gives me the same result: time out response

Comment: It could still be a firewall issue: when using `--net=host`, access is controlled by the `INPUT` chain, while without it access is controlled by the `FORWARD` chain (and rules in the `nat` table). Consider restarting the docker daemon (which will cause it to re-create any critical missing firewall rules) to see if that has any impact on the situation.

Comment: I have restarted the service with `systemctl restart docker`. I still have the same issue. Do you have some tips for how can I check if requests are filtered by the FORWARD chain ?

Comment: are you running docker on windows? if yes, probably you need configure your virtualmachine to expose ports. Otherwise sounds like a firewall issue.


Another idea is use nginx as gateway

Comment: The host is a running VM. Maybe the issue is from there. The sysadmin told me he added the exception for the port and i think it works. (Because if I run the container in host network I can access jenkins from my computer). I do like the idea of using nginx on port 80 on host network. Can I run nginx on multiple networks ? (host network and private docker)

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue. If I run postgresql directly from the host it can be acessible by anyone, but if I run via docker it is being acessed only from localhost, but not from other physical hosts.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue while running the nginx container under AWS EC2 instance with Ubuntu 22.X. The following actions worked for me:

1. Forward IPV4 packets to all interfaces (You can also choose specific interface if you like):

> ```
> sudo sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1
> ```

2. Set the default policy for the FORWARD chain to ACCEPT in the linux iptables firewall:

> ```
>  sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
> ```

Please note that through the above 2 commands, you are allowing all the traffic to be forwarded between interfaces. You can go more specific if you like though.

Also these iptable rules will not persist after the reboot so you may need to write these permanently into concerned configuration files.

---

The following commands may be useful for tracing purposes:

1. TCP dump for the docker bridge to see the incoming traffic:  `sudo tcpdump -i docker0`
2. Listing Kernel NAT Rules:  `sudo iptables -t nat -L -n`